# csv with dates in decimal format

Tags: r, csv, highcharts

I've been provided a csv file with the date column as follows:

```
1990.12466
1990.20137
1990.2863
1990.36849
1990.45342
1990.53562
1990.62055
1990.70548
1990.78767
1990.8726
1990.95479
1991.03973
```

This is data I'll be using in highcharts, I can't seem to find any functionality to get these formats into YYYYMMDD

It appears like this data was made in R using something like the lubridate function but I have no way of confirming this.

Any ideas on the best way to get this data into YYYMMDD ?

Comment: Do you know what the _actual_ dates are? Ex: 1990.12466 = 07/18/1990

Comment: I do not unfortunately

Comment: Ok, in that case, I have to assume the first four digits represent the year, and the digits after the decimal represent the percentage through the year. Ex. 1990.12466 => year=1990; month=02; day=15. I get that by taking 0.12466 multiplied by 365 (45 days into the year), which lands on 2/15/1990. Do you think that is a safe assumption?

Comment: If so: [Converting date in Year.decimal form in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965699/converting-date-in-year-decimal-form-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the first four digits represent the year, and the digits after the decimal represent the percentage through the year, you can use the following formula to convert these values into a MS Excel date-time code: (with dates to be converted residing in column "A")

```
=DATE(MID(A1,1,4),1,1)+((A1-MID(A1,1,4))*(IF(OR(MOD(MID(A1,1,4),400)=0,AND(MOD(MID(A1,1,4),4)=0,MOD(MID(A1,1,4),100)<>0)),365, 366)))
```

Once you have these MS Excel date-time codes, you can format the date in Excel to whatever format you need (see [Format a date the way you want](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. First we linearly interpolate between the beginning of the year and the end of the year, and then we format the output into YYYYMMDD format as requested:

```
decimal_to_date = function(dt){
  yr = floor(dt)
  yr_begin = ISOdate(yr, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
  yr_end = ISOdate(yr+1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
  interpolated_date = yr_begin + (yr_end - yr_begin) * (dt - yr)
  return(format(interpolated_date, '%Y%m%d'))
}
```

Then for example `decimal_to_date(1990.12466)` returns `19900215` for February 15, 1990.
If you output the times as well as the dates, the time of day is always very near noon, which suggests something about the process that generated your data, although I'm not exactly sure what.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's a very slight variation on [Michael Lugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556369/michael-lugo)'s answer, which indeed does the trick. The `ISOdate()` function outputs a date-time object. Following code uses `as.Date()` which outputs date only. Following code also takes a brief shortcut in the calculation of the number of days in a calendar year - which you'll need for the interpolation. This shortcut requires loading a library, however, which the original answer does not.

```
library(lubridate)
decimals <- c(1990.12466,1990.20137,1990.2863,1990.36849,1990.45342,1990.53562,1990.62055,1990.70548,1990.78767,1990.8726,1990.95479,1991.03973)

decimal_to_date2 = function(dt){
  nDays <- yday(paste0(floor(dt),"-12-31"))
  day1 <- as.Date(paste0(floor(dt),"-01-01"))
  interpolated_date <- day1+(dt-floor(dt))*nDays
  return(format(interpolated_date, '%Y%m%d'))
}
decimal_to_date2(decimals)
```

Results of first answer and mine are identical.